# Could not set the accurate content security policy in Angular4

Tags: javascript, angular

I am getting the following error while setting the `content-security-policy`.

**Error:**

> Refused to connect to 'http://localhost:3000/articles' because it
>   violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src
>   'self' 'unsafe-eval' ws:". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly
>   set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

I am explaining my code below.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
  content="default-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' ws:;
  style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
  script-src 'self' http://localhost:4200 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';">
```

In my code I am also connecting to `json` server to read/write the data into json file which run at `http://localhost:3000/articles` but here I am getting those related error and this is my angular4 code. I need some help to resolve this error.

Comment: Are you using Rails for BackEnd or another Framework ??

Comment: No backend only I have this `crud` app in angular4 and I am storing the form data into json file and read,edit,update it.

Comment: I faced this problem in different framework and the solution was editing configuration of backend config server . So I think that the solution is to edit in some of your server config file to enable CORS on static files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question right, I think your angular app runs on localhost:4200 and the API service on localhost:3000? This would explain why you have got that CSP warning as the request is from different source according to your current CSP configuration.

Also, ideally, the CSP should be delivered via HTTP header which means you will need some kind of server backing to support that. For example, you can have a ASP.NET app that hosts the angular app and the CSP then can be configured via web.config file.

In your case, if it's purely frontend, then perhaps you could alter your CSP setting to something like this. Hopefully it works for you.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
  content="default-src 'self' http://localhost:3000/ 'unsafe-eval' ws:;
  style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
  script-src 'self' http://localhost:4200 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';">
```

Comment: Perfect. Your understanding is correct as per my problem . This code working fine. Thank you.